# VLC Playback Stutters with ProRes-encoded Video

Tags: video, ffmpeg, vlc-media-player, codec, video-playback

I have a 4K 60fps 3.46 GB video file that was encoded from a lossless 8bpc RGB mov video file using the following ffmpeg settings:

`ffmpeg -i 8bpcRGB.mov -c:v prores_ks -profile:v 2 -bits_per_mb 540 -vendor apl0 -pix_fmt yuv422p10le "out.mov"`

However, when I attempt to play this 4K 60fps 3.46 GB "out.mov" file in VLC media player, I notice that the playback stutters and sometimes stops for seconds at a time. If I were to instead encode the video file using:

`ffmpeg -i 8bpcRGB.mov -c:v libx264 -x264-params "nal-hrd=cbr" -b:v 30M -minrate 30M -maxrate 30M -bufsize 2M -pix_fmt yuv420p "out.mp4`

Then "out.mp4" plays back perfectly in VLC. So clearly the reason that "out.mov" is stuttering so badly has something to do with the codec or potentially the file size or both. I'm curious what hardware/software aspect of my system is repsponsible for the poor playback; I have a few ideas of what it might be:

- VLC isn't optimized enough to decode this particular prores codec in realtime (software limitation).
- The disk drive that the video file resides on is not fast enough for VLC to read in the data it needs for playback in realtime (hardware limitation).
- My CPU isn't fast enough to perform the decoding in realtime (hardware limitation).

**Which one is it, or is it something else altogether? What do you think?**

I have an Intel i7 6820HK. The file is located on an external WD MyBook Duo in RAID 1 connected to the computer via USB 3.0. However, I seem to notice this playback problem even when the file is located on the internal Samsung 951 SSD

Comment: What are the specs of your system? You mentioned suspicion of your CPU but we can't really rule that out or confirm it when we don't know what you're using.

Comment: @MMM, Intel i7 6820HK. The file is located on an external WD MyBook Duo in RAID 1 connected to the computer via USB 3.0. However, I seem to notice this playback problem even when the file is located on the internal Samsung 951 SSD.

Comment: Your SSD can definitely read much more than that, and even your external drive should handle these data rates just fine, but obviously it's going to be hard to decode that much data with that mobile CPU of yours. I assume that this will be the bottleneck. Hard to prove though. I think Apple's QuickTime is more performant than VLC, but I've never tried ProRes outside of macOS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This fixed it for me on Windows 10 in VLC 3.0.16:

Tools -> Preferences -> Video -> Set "Output" to "OpenGL video output for Windows"

Then close VLC and launch it again.

After that, my 4K ProRes playback was smooth in VLC.

I'm not sure sure if there are any downsides to leaving it on Open GL rendering all the time, as opposed to the default "Automatic" setting.

Comment: Wow that's crazy it actually worked. Although it seems inconsistent, some of my videos get frozen.

Comment: This workaround worked for me, thank you so much.

Comment: Note: I just modified my suggested setting from "OpenGL video output" to "OpenGL video output for Windows". On my system, the former leads to an invisible mouse cursor over the video window, while the latter does not.